# Sorting in Search.asmx querypacket

Tags: enterprise-search, query

I have this querypacket to query Search.asmx service, and get back the results, stored in queryXML object, I can retrieve data successfully, but I can't figure out how to sort this data on any field I need, currently I need to sort data by Modified Date, but I can't even sort it on the Title column.

I tried write `<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Write' Type='Date' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy>`

I also tried `<SortByProperties> <SortByProperty name='Write' direction='Ascending'/></SortByProperties>`

Also didn't work, here is the full querypacket:

```
"<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>
            <Query domain='QDomain'>
             <SupportedFormats>
                <Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document</Format> 
             </SupportedFormats> 
             <Context> 
               <QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT' > 
              <![CDATA[ SELECT Title, Path, Description, Rank,  FirstName, LastName , Write, PictureURL FROM scope() 
              WHERE CONTAINS(*,'\"" + query + "*\"') AND \"scope\" = '" + scopetype + "' 
              ]]></QueryText> 
             </Context> 
<OrderBy>
         <FieldRef Name='Title' Type = 'Text' Ascending='False'/>   
                    </OrderBy>
             <Range><StartAt>"+(1+(quickSearchSelectedPageIndex*quickSearchConfig.numberOfResults))+"</StartAt> 
             <Count>" + quickSearchConfig.numberOfResults + "</Count></Range> 
             <EnableStemming>false</EnableStemming> 
             <TrimDuplicates>true</TrimDuplicates>  
             <IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>true</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery> 
             <ImplicitAndBehavior>true</ImplicitAndBehavior> 
             <IncludeRelevanceResults>true</IncludeRelevanceResults> 
             <IncludeSpecialTermResults>true</IncludeSpecialTermResults> 
             <IncludeHighConfidenceResults>true</IncludeHighConfidenceResults> 
            </Query></QueryPacket>";
```

Note that scopetype is a variable indicating the scope, and the query is the string of my real query.

Comment: So you just get not sorted data in response, or is there some error?

Comment: No error at all, but the latest document doesn't appear to be the first one, I have them in Ascending Order depending on the date, and can't get them to be in Descending Order, I tried several methods for the ordering as described, but didn't work, but no errors at all. 

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked that the managed properties are configured as Sortable?

Comment: Where do I check that from?

Comment: That depends on the version of SharePoint you're using. For SP2013 it would be smth like Central administration -> Search Service Application => Search Schema => Managed Properties => Edit property => Sortable => set to Yes. For SP2010,  Central Administration => Search Service Application => Managed Properties => tick ON the checkbox "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison"

Comment: The comment by @AndreyMarkeev helped me to solve this problem